# Automated way of printing (a) (b) (c) before my string?

Tags: python

How can I get my python code to print (a), (b), (c) etc... before it prints out strings, each on a new line... effectively numbering them

```
for x in range(10):
        print(LIST[x])
```

At the moment this just prints:

LIST VALUE 1

LIST VALUE 2

LIST VAULE 3

*and so on until 10...*

How can I get it to print:

(a) LIST VALUE 1

(b) LIST VALUE 2

(c) LIST VALUE 3

*and so on until 10...*

The reason I want this is because it is part of a larger project which is a multiple choice quiz so it would be like: *"Whats 2 + 2?" choose (a), (b) or (c)*

Thanks!

Comment: How do you intend to handle lists with more than 26 items?  Start labeling them `'(aa)'`, `'(ab)'`, ...?  Raise a `ValueError`?

Comment: Hi @KevinJ.Chase That is very good point you raised... The program only prints 3 - 5 options at a time so it will never need to print (a) (b) (c) up to (z) and beyond :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in range(10):
        print("("+chr(ord('a')+x)+")"+str(LIST[x]))
```

chr creates a character.

Character of 97 is a

98 is b

99 is c and so on

Comment: Hi @JeD I got: "TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly"

Comment: I still have: "TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly".... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` it with the `string.ascii_lowercase`

```
import string

for letter, answer in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, LIST):
     print '({}) {}'.format(letter, answer)
```

**NOTE:** When iterating over a list you don't have to use indexing, you can just say

```
for thing in my_list:
```

Comment: This is a _much_ more obvious and Pythonic way to do it, rather than mucking around with manual conversions involving `ord` and `chr` and indexing to get individual values from `LIST` over and over, and it should really be the accepted answer. All those conversions and indexing operations make sense in C, but in Python, they're slower, less readable, and more verbose to boot, a trifecta of terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of the values to lookup in

```
lookup = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)] # 97 - 122 inclusive
```

This creates a list `['a','b',...]`.

And then in your print statement, do

```
print("({}) {}".format(lookup[x],LIST[x]))
```

The format method replaces the occurrences of `{}` with the two specfied values.

Comment: `range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)`. I feel grumpy today.

Comment: @pelya I think I changed it _just_ before you posted that ;-)